# Best approach to call Java function from JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI and I was wondering what's the best approach to call `Java function from JNI.
My requiremenets:

1. `start` from `TestClass` may be called from different threads
2. `onSomethingHappened` from `MyCallbackCass` is triggered after some time
   (not immediately) lets say after 30 seconds when start was triggered

Here's my code snippet:

`NativeJNI.cpp` file

```
static JavaVM* g_JavaVM = NULL;
MyCallbackCass *callbackClass = new MyCallbackCass();

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    g_JavaVM = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

// class to atach JNIEnv because method may be called from different Threads
class AttachedEnv final {
private:
    JNIEnv *mEnv;
    bool needDetach;

    int getEnv(JNIEnv **g_env) {
        int getEnvStat = g_JavaVM->GetEnv((void **) g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
            if (g_JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(g_env, nullptr) != 0) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "GetEnvironmentRoutine", "FAILED ATTACH THREAD");
                return 2; //Failed to attach
            }
            return 1; //Attached. Need detach
        }
        return 0;//Already attached
    }

public:
    AttachedEnv() {
        auto resCode = getEnv(&mEnv);
        if (resCode == 2)
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot retrieve JNI environment");
        needDetach = (resCode == 1);
    }

    ~AttachedEnv() {
        if (needDetach) {
            g_JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
        }
    }

    JNIEnv *env() const noexcept {
        return mEnv;
    }
};


class MyCallbackCass : MyCustomCallback {
    private: 
        jobject m_Obj;

    MyCallbackCass() {

    }

    void setEnvVariables(jobject obj) {
        this->m_Obj = obj; // I really doubt about this line
    }

     virtual void onSomethingHappened() override {
        // Here I need to call Java method from JNI
          AttachedEnv attachedEnv;
         JNIEnv *env = attachedEnv.env();

         jclass objClass = env->GetObjectClass(m_Obj); // is it a good approach? Is a good idea to have m_Obj in my class?
         mFunctionId = env->GetMethodID(objClass, "callbackedCalled", "(Z)V");

         env->CallVoidMethod(m_Obj, mFunctionId, true);
     }
}


void Java_com_playground_TestClass_start(JNIEnv *env, jobject dispatcher) {
    callbackClass->setEnvVariables(dispatcher) // I don't think this is a good approach
}
```

Koltin file

```
@Keep
class TestClass {
    fun onStartClicked() {
        start()
    }

    external fun start()

    fun callbackedCalled(value: Boolean) {
        Timber.d("Callback from JNI was called with value $value")
    }

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("DemoJNI")
        }
    }
}
```

This code works. So my main concerns:
Is it really a good approach to pass `jobject` dispatcher to my callback class?
Is it possible to have global `jobject` and somehow init it in `JNI_OnLoad`?
May you have some suggestions or improvements?
Thank you for your answers and time.

Comment: 1) start threads from java so you can avoid need for `AttachedEnv` 2) keep attention to reference counting: if you want to keep `jobject` you must make a global reference and so on

Comment: If you're going to effectively keep a single global variable anyway, I suggest you keep it alive from the Java side as a static variable there, that you can then fetch from JNI.